# How to deal with /system/files references when upgrading to D7?

Tags: files, upgrading

After migrating a site from D6 to D7 with `drush site-upgrade`, I notice that some public contents in the D6 version refered to pictures with URIs like for instance `/system/files/logo.png`, instead of the more efficient `/sites/default/files/logo.png`
There's no `system` directory on disk and no URL rewriting that I can see, so I assume the first form goes to Drupal for routing.

The problem is that with D7 post-upgrade, such references lead to a *"Page not found"* error so the pictures are broken.

As a test, if I drop `somefile.png` into `/sites/default/files/`, D6 seems to be happy to serve http://example.com/system/files/somefile.png despite the fact that the file is not known anywhere in its database. But D7 apparently doesn't do that.

Is `/system/files` a hardcoded path component that means something to D6 and not D7?
In `/admin/config/media/file-system`, the download method is set to "Public local files served..."

How to solve this with Drupal 7? Is there a configuration setting somewhere that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it happens

In D6, the `system` module provides the following menu entry that ties `system/files` to the `file_download` callback:

In `system_menu()` function:

```
  $items['system/files'] = array(
    'title' => 'File download',
    'page callback' => 'file_download',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

Then in `file_download(),` if the file exists and no `hook_file_download()` objects to the download, it gets served.

On the other hand, D7 expands on that with a page argument set to `private`:

```
  $items['system/files'] = array(
    'title' => 'File download',
    'page callback' => 'file_download',
    'page arguments' => array('private'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

It has the effect of preprending the `private://` scheme to the filename, which `file_download` processes by requesting the registered file stream wrapper for  it.
By default (no private path set in `/admin/config/media/file-system`), this scheme is not registered, and that's why `GET /system/files/logo.png` finally fails with a 404 status.

### How to fix

Setting the private file system path to `sites/default/files` (the same as the public path) makes it work.

However it's not a good long term fix, both because routing public static files through Drupal is much heavier than direct access by httpd, and because it precludes the use of a real private space should the site need it in the future.

The long term fix is to hunt for these `/system/files/xyz` references and replace them by `/sites/default/files/xyz`.